# How to draw an angle on a graph

Tags: pgfplots, axis, tikz-angles

So I have tried a variety of methods. `\scope` seems to move my graph to the side, as does the usage of `tikz-euclide`, as opposed to drawing over my graph.

```
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[xlabel={$x$}, ylabel={$z$}, axis equal, xticklabels={,,}, yticklabels={,,},axis x line=middle, axis y line=
middle, ymin=-1, xmin=-1]
        \addplot[mark=none,solid, color=black]{x};
        \addplot[mark=none,solid, color=black, domain=0:(4/(1+cot(deg((3*pi)/8))))]{4-x*cot(deg((3*pi)/8))};
        \coordinate (A) at (0,1);
        \coordinate (B) at (0,0);
        \coordinate (C) at (1,1);
        \pic [draw,-, black, angle eccentricity=1.2,"$\theta$"] {angle = (A)--(B)--(C)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Using `\pic` is the only way I know how to make an angle in a `tikzpicture` environment, however for some reason, latex doesn't recognise (B). The packages I am using are:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,quotes}
```

[image]

I wish to generate an angle theta against the x axis and the line z=x

Comment: If your only goal is to draw this diagram, you should go for plain Ti*k*Z instead of pgfplots, much more flexible and easy to learn.

Comment: I also plan to graph complicated equations

Comment: @yolo you can also graph using TikZ. `pgfplots` really comes into play if you also want the corresponding axis and labels (and a legend), because that is much simpler to do. That being said thoug, you can easily use regular `tikz` command within the `axes` environment. You just have to pick the correct axis system for your coordinates (see `pgfplots` manual)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the `angle` `\pic` wrong, it should be just the coordinate names, without the parentheses. I.e.

```
\pic [draw,-, black, angle eccentricity=1.2,"$\theta$"] {angle = C--B--A};
```

I've also swapped the order there to get the angle in the first quadrant.

[image]

You also need to set the `compat` version to 1.11 or higher (e.g. `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}`), to make the `\coordinate` specification work. Otherwise coordinates used in `\coordinate`, `\draw`, `\path` etc. won't be interpreted as being in the `axis` coordinate system.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,quotes}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
    
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[xlabel={$x$}, ylabel={$z$}, axis equal, xticklabels={,,}, yticklabels={,,},axis x line=middle, axis y line=
middle, ymin=-1, xmin=-1]
        \addplot[mark=none,solid, color=black]{x};
        \addplot[mark=none,solid, color=black, domain=0:(4/(1+cot(deg((3*pi)/8))))]{4-x*cot(deg((3*pi)/8))};
        \coordinate (A) at (0,1);
        \coordinate (B) at (0,0);
        \coordinate (C) at (1,1);
        \pic [draw,-, black, angle eccentricity=1.2,"$\theta$"] {angle = C--B--A};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Right, didn't realize you wrote "between x-axis and z=x", I just assumed you'd defined A, B and C correctly. As you can see, the `A` coordinate is placed on the y-axis, move it to the x-axis and swap the order for the angle pic back to `A--B--C` to get the angle where you described it.

Comment: Is it possible to draw the angle without defining three `coordinate`s?  I tried
`\pic [draw,-, black, angle eccentricity=1.2,"$\theta$"] {angle = {(0,1)}--{(0,0)}--{(1,1)};` but it didn't work.

Comment: @tush No. Quote from the manual: "The three points ⟨A⟩, ⟨B⟩, and ⟨C⟩ must be the names of nodes or coordinates; you cannot use direct coordinates like “(1,1)” here."

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=.5cm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]
        \draw[brown!15] (-1,-1) grid[step=.2] (3,2);
        \draw[gray!35] (-1,-1) grid (3,2);
        \draw[-latex]   (-1,0) -- (3,0) node[right] {$x$};
        \draw[-latex]   (0,-1) -- (0,2) node[above] {$y$};
        \node at (-.1,-.1) (o) {$O$};
        \node at (1,-.1) (o) {$1$};
        \node at (-.1,1) (o) {$1$};
        
        \draw[blue,line width=2pt] (0,0)--(3,1.732); % 3*tan(30°)=1.732
        \draw[red] (1,0) arc (0:30:1);
        \node[red] at (1.1,.25) {$\theta$};
    
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output:
[image]